# MySQL Select Select "or" and Order by that field

Tags: php, mysql, select

Table:

```
| object_id  |     term_taxonomy_id   |
|-----1------|-------------2----------|
|-----2------|-------------2----------|
|-----1------|-------------3----------|
|-----3------|-------------2----------|
|-----4------|-------------3----------|
|-----4------|-------------2----------|
```

Using the MySQL I want to select the distinct *object_id* where taxonomy is either 2 or 3, and order it by taxonomy desc.

I have tried this below, which basically works, though when you add DISTINCT it doesn't then order the results.

```
 $sql_feed = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id='2' OR term_taxonomy_id='3' ORDER BY term_taxonomy_id DESC");
```

I have no doubt this is a very simple adjustment I need to make; it just isn't one that I have had to do before and I haven't been able to find the answer which fits all the criteria.

Comment: What would be your expected result? It would seem it orders correctly, `4 3`, `1 3`, `2 2`, `3 2` by second number descending.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson 1, 4, 2, 3.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson 1 and 4 are first because they have the taxonomy result of 3 (and we are ordering DESC).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into here is that the query is ordering the terms, then picking distinct ones, giving you unordered results again. What you want to do instead is use `GROUP BY` to group the results first, then order by the max of each group so that your `DISTINCT` clause picks out only one item from each group...

```
SELECT DISTINCT object_id
FROM wp_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id='2' OR term_taxonomy_id='3'
GROUP BY object_id
ORDER BY MAX(term_taxonomy_id) DESC
```

<strike>As a side-note, you should move away from the old `mysql_` functions, which are now deprecated as of PHP 5.5, and move towards parameterised queries with MySQLi or PDO. This keeps you in-line with the latest updates and helps improve your security against attacks such as SQL injection.</strike> *Edit: whoops - misread your code!*

Comment: My bad, I misread the name. I've seen it done wrong so many times already today that it's messing with my eyes!

Comment: I thought to myself "surely I am using mysqli". Thankfully I was!

Comment: By using max though it seams to only output the results where it has both 2 and 3 taxonomy (i.e. what should be first)